# i used google sign in authentication with firebase and now i want to display the data the current user saved but its not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used Google Sign in authentication with firebase. when the google user logs into the application and saves a data to firebase, the user should be able to retrieve the data which they saved earlier on based on their id.
this is the code to save the data to firebase

```
public class UpdateMedicalProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser fuser;
    Intent intent;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    private Button updateProfilebtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_medical_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        updateProfilebtn = findViewById(R.id.updateProfile);
        FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        String userid =user.getUid();

        myRef.child(userid).setValue(user);

        updateProfilebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDetails();
            }
        });

        //String Names = name.getText().toString();

        intent = getIntent();
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    }


    public void updateMedicalProfile(String name, String age, String bloodgroup, String allergy ){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users Medicals");
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("name", name);
        hashMap.put("age", age);
        hashMap.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
        hashMap.put("allergy", allergy);
        reference.child("Medical Info").push().setValue(hashMap);
    }

    public void updateDetails() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userEmail = user.getEmail();
        EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText age = findViewById(R.id.age);
        EditText bloodgroup = findViewById(R.id.bloodgroup);
        EditText allergy = findViewById(R.id.allergy);

        String Names = name.getText().toString();
        String Ages = age.getText().toString();
        String bloodGroup = bloodgroup.getText().toString();
        String Allergy = allergy.getText().toString();
        String btnUpdateProfile = updateProfilebtn.getText().toString();


        if (!Names.isEmpty() && !Ages.isEmpty() && !bloodGroup.isEmpty() && !Allergy.isEmpty() && ! btnUpdateProfile.isEmpty() ) {
            updateMedicalProfile(Names, Ages, bloodGroup, Allergy);
            Toast.makeText(UpdateMedicalProfile.this,
                    "Profile Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(UpdateMedicalProfile.this,
                    "You can't send an empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //  report.setText("");

    }
}
```

This is the code to retrieve the data that the specific user saved

```
public class HomeFragment3 extends Fragment {
View homeView3;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference, rootRef;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

TextView vName, vAge, vBloodGroup,vAllergy;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        homeView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragment3, container, false);

        vName = homeView3.findViewById(R.id.view_name);
        vAge =  homeView3.findViewById(R.id.view_age);
        vBloodGroup =  homeView3.findViewById(R.id.view_bloodGroup);
        vAllergy =  homeView3.findViewById(R.id.view_allergy);      

        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users Medicals");
        databaseReference = rootRef.child("Medical Info");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String Name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String Age = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                    String BloodGroup = ds.child("bloodgroup").getValue(String.class);
                    String Allergy = ds.child("allergy").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", Name + " / " + Age + " / " + BloodGroup + " / " + Allergy );
                    vName.setText(Name);
                    vAge.setText(Age);
                    vBloodGroup.setText(BloodGroup);
                    vAllergy.setText(Allergy);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);





        return homeView3;
    }


}
```

please what am i doing wrong

Comment: What error are u getting

Comment: Also add ur database

Comment: its only displaying the last data i save. even when i use a different google account to log in

Comment: Since the answer helped you please upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to it and mark it as correct by clicking the check mark thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener)
```

Into this:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(eventListener)
```

The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will retrieve data only once